# How does /reports redirect to the SQL server reporting page

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server

I'm working on creating a report page for an ASP.NET project, the url to that page is

```
'localhost/reports'
```

But for some reason, the SQL Server reporting page is turned on and now there is a url conflict.

So my url now redirects me to the following url:

```
'localhost/Reports/Pages/Folder.aspx'
```

It seems the behavior of '/reports' is overwritten by the SQL Report Service site. I would like to know how to turn on/off the db service(report browsing) site manually or by DDL change

Comment: Why not just make your name more specific, like SalesReports rather than just Reports?

Comment: Just curious where the problem is

Comment: I would suspect this is setup under IIS management as some sort of virtual path.  But as Jody mentions generally you edit it from RS Config.  Certainly if it is on the same port 80 as IIS is listening on, then IIS is involved in some way to direct the request to Reporting Services.

Comment: @AaronLS Could u give me a short example, i'm not quite familar with IIS virtual path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can turn of the entire reporting service in the `SQL Server Configuration Manager` or you can go to the `Reporting Services Configuration Manager` and change the `Report Manager URL` to point to a different location. The default is /Reports.

Answer (score 2):

If you look under "Internet Information Services (IIS) Management", I usually just search for it from start menu, you will see an app pool for reporting services/SSRS with a Reports entry under it.  You will probably also see an entry under Default Website.  Unfortunately different versions of IIS manager will look different.  If you find the "Reports" entry under the Websites/Sites entry, and right click you may have a Properties or Manage Virtual Directory option.  Basically IIS handles routing requests to different web applications.  So each web application that wants to handle a certain base URL must be configured here.  Often times this is done without your knowledge through a deployment or install process, but for more complex setups you might modify IIS directly.

Basically you have a situation where your app and SSRS both have a path in IIS that responds to /reports/.  As JodyT answered, the correct solution is to modify the Reporting Manager URL(which likely in turn modifies IIS).  I wouldn't be surprised if you had to reboot or run IISReset to get this change picked up.  It's hard to say sometimes, but hopefully not.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change Configuration for SSRS.
Follow these Step:

1. Open Reporting Services Configuration Manager
2. Click on Reporting Manager URL
3. In virtual Directory Change Folder Name 'Reports' to 'Reports2'
4. Click Apply
5. Now Check website